# Initialise const member with make_shared

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, shared-ptr, make-shared

The following code compiles using Xcode 6.3.2 but not Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <memory>

class Y
{
public:
    Y(uint32_t i) : m_i(i)
    {
    }

private:
    uint32_t m_i;
};

class X
{
public:
    X() = default;

private:
    const uint32_t m_dimension = 2;
    const std::shared_ptr<Y> m_y = std::make_shared<Y>(m_dimension);
};
```

The error reported is:

```
error C2783: 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty> std::make_shared(_Types &&...)' : could not deduce template argument for '_Ty'
```

Could this be a compiler bug in Visual Studio or is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: this code compiles without any error on Visual 2013 (Update 4). To generate this error I have to write `make_shared(` instead of `make_shared<Y>(`

Comment: It appears this bug has been [documented](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/818825/torino-in-class-member-initialization-using-std-make-shared-type-fails-to-compile)

Comment: @Hcorg - Update 4? How do I find that information? I see only: 
Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop
Version 12.0.21005.1 REL
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50938

Comment: @ksl My 2013 Update 4 shows 12.0.31101.00 Update 4. But as of today, you can just jump to 2015!

Comment: @Alejandro Thanks. Do you want to put that as an answer and I'll accept it?

Comment: @ksl if you don't see any "Update X" text, than you have old, not patched version - as Alejandro wrote - update 2013 or try 2015

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears as though you're not the only one with this issue -- this bug has been [documented](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedbackdetail/view/818825/torino-in-class-member-initialization-using-std-make-shared-type-fails-to-compile)! Newer versions of Visual Studio shouldn't have this issue (Update 4 of Visual Studio 2013 seems to be the starting point).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with VS2013 update 4 and have resolved it by updating it to version 5.